# Умные указатели в C++

Tags: c++

```
void setQuackBehavior(QuackBehavior & qb) {
    quackBehavior = std::move(std::shared_ptr<QuackBehavior> (&qb));
}
```

Есть метод `setQuackBehavior()`, который принимает ссылку на абстрактный класс `QuackBehavior`. Этот метод находится в классе, который имеет член `std::shared_ptr<QuackBehavior> quackBehavior`.

Может ли код, который приведён выше, иметь право на существование? По-моему тут всё хорошо, но мало ли я что-то не учитываю, и в примере этого кода имеется какая-либо грубая ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой подход **имеет ряд недостатков**.

1. Создание объекта отдельно от создание указателя.
2. Код выше должен гарантировать, что объект создается с помощью new.
3. Код выше должен гарантировать, что объект нигде не удаляется.
4. Код выше должен гарантировать, что в объекте, на который ссылается qb нет умных указателей на наш объект (который this в данной функции-члене).
5. Код выше должен гарантировать, что больше нет умных указателей на данный объект.

## Теперь по каждому пункту подробнее.

**1)** Когда Вы создаете `shared_ptr`, выделяется блок динамической памяти для хранения служебных данных, например, счетчик ссылок, собственный delete'ор и т.д.
Таким образом, у Вас будет одно выделение памяти для создания объекта, и одно для создания этого блока служебных данных. И объект и данные также будут лежать в разных участках памяти, поэтому, такая структура, помимо лишнего выделения памяти может еще быть не дружелюбной к кешу.
Для того, чтобы выделить память под объект и указателя рядом, одним выделением, можно использовать `std::make_shared`. Она за одно выделение памяти сделает и указатель и динамический блок с данными.

**2)** Для данного `shared_ptr` не указан пользовательский метод удаления, а значит будет использоваться `delete`, поэтому объект должен быть создан с помощью `new`.

**3)** Объект будет автоматически уничтожен при уничтожении последнего умного указателя ссылки на него. Согласитесь, при вызове setQuackBehavior совершенно не очевидно, что внутри на объект создается `shared_ptr`.

```
Derived derived = new Derived;
obj.setQuackBehavior(*derived);
```

Возможно, когда-нибудь дальше появится что-то вроде `delete derived;` или еще-что-нибудь подобное.

**4)** Это скорее не к конкретно этому коду, а вообще к любому коду с shared_ptr. Если два объекта содержат указатели на друг друга (или более сложная схема), то это приведет к циклическим ссылкам и, фактически, к утечкам.

**5)** Этот код требует гарантии, что на этот объект более нет умных указателей.

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived(new Derived);//или make_shared
obj.setQuackBehavior(*derived);//Злостная ошибка
```

При таком (или подобном) коде на один объект `derived` теперь приходится два блока со служебными данными для разных `shared_ptr`, а значит у нас и два счетчика ссылок и т.д. Эти указатели теперь живут "раздельно" и не знают о существовании друг друга. Понятное дело, что это приведет к преждевременному удалению объекта, обращению к несуществующим данным, прострелам памяти, двойному удалению и всем-всем прелестям не верной работы с памятью.

Ну и в Вашем коде лишний std::move. Объект и так временный, поэтому будет перемещен, а не скопирован.

Почему бы не сделать так:

```
void setQuackBehavior(std::shared_ptr<QuackBehavior> const &qb) {
    quackBehavior = qb;
}
```

Сразу очевидно, что работаем с `shared_ptr`, код Выше его создает, поэтому он может воспользоваться `make_shared`, что положительно скажется на программе, также очевидно, что раз внутри `shared_ptr`, то не нужно удалять объект, а также нужно учесть возможность циклических ссылок.

```
obj.setQuackBehavior(std::make_shared<Derived>());
```

По-моему, такой код более очевиден и безопасен.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень ясен смысл делать `move` для `shared_ptr`. Т.к. при обычном копировании вполне нормально инкрементируется счётчик ссылок.

А ошибка может быть в двойном удалении объекта, на который ссылается `qb`. Первый раз как обычный объект (надо смотреть код, где создаётся объект исходно), второй - при вызове деструктора последнего объекта `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Исходно объект создается в int main().  То есть так делать не следует?

Comment: @Кирилл если создаётся через `new`, и потом не вызывается явный `delete`, то будет работать, хоть это и криво. Если просто на стеке - получите двойное удаление.

Comment: Понял. Благодарю.

Comment: @Кирилл пожалуйста, но лучше, приводите в вопросе больше контекста. Можете ознакомиться о том, что такое [mcve], если планируете ещё вопросы в дальнейшем на сайте задавать.

Comment: @Кирилл Хочешь работать с shared_ptr привыкай использовать `make_shared`. Например, `a = std::make_shared<A>(arg1, arg2, ...)`